# DAX counts rows between 2 dates

Tags: date, count, rows, dax, between

```html
DECLARE @lower INT = 1
 ,@upper INT = 6
 ,@randnum INT
 ,@date DATE = getdate()
 ,@endofcurrentmonth DATE
 ,@loopdate DATE
 ,@loop INT
 ,@loopmax INT
 ,@innerloop INT
 ,@innerloopmax INT
 ,@value DATE

IF object_id('tempdb..#tmp_DateRange') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #tmp_DateRange

CREATE TABLE #tmp_DateRange (
 ID INT identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
 ,[Date] DATE
 )

IF object_id('tempdb..#tmp_RandomData') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #tmp_RandomData

CREATE TABLE #tmp_RandomData (
 ID INT identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
 ,[BidDateWon] DATE
 ,[BidWon] BIT
 )

SELECT @endofcurrentmonth = dateadd(mm, datediff(MM, 0, dateadd(MM, 1, @date)), 0) - 1

SELECT @loopdate = dateadd(mm, - 9, dateadd(dd, 1 - datepart(dd, @date), @date))

WHILE @loopdate <= @endofcurrentmonth
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #tmp_DateRange ([Date])
 VALUES (@loopdate)

 SET @loopdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @loopdate)
END

SELECT @loop = 0
 ,@loopmax = max(ID)
FROM #tmp_DateRange

WHILE @loop < @loopmax
BEGIN
 SELECT @randnum = round(((@upper - @lower - 1) * rand() + @lower), 0)

 SET @loop = @loop + 1
 SET @innerloopmax = @randnum
 SET @innerloop = 0

 IF @randnum % 2 = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @value = (
    SELECT [date]
    FROM #tmp_DateRange
    WHERE ID = @loop
    )
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @value = NULL
 END

 WHILE @innerloop <= @innerloopmax
 BEGIN
  SET @innerloop = @innerloop + 1

  INSERT INTO #tmp_RandomData (BidDateWon)
  VALUES (@value)
 END
END

UPDATE #tmp_RandomData
SET BidWon = 1
WHERE BidDateWon IS NOT NULL

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_RandomData
```

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fact_SalesSummaries),
     DATESINPERIOD(Fact_SalesSummaries[BidWonDate],
         LASTDATE(Fact_SalesSummaries[BidWonDate]),
         -3, MONTH),
     Fact_SalesSummaries[BidWonDate] <> BLANK())
```

I have tried search and different ways to counts rows that have dates between 2 different dates it calculates the rows as 1 and not more than that in the formula.

This is meant to be a rolling 3-month count of records from date back 3 months to be able to calculate an average with a count of all records.

Example in SQL would look like this.

```html
select MonthBlended, yearblended, BidWonDate, BidWonFlag,
(select count(*) from Fact_SalesSummaries
 where convert(date, cast(MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101) between 
 dateadd(mm, -3, convert(date, cast(t1.MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(t1.YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101))
 and convert(date, cast(t1.MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(t1.YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101)
 and BidWonDate is not null
 ) as CountWONPrior3Month,
(select count(*) from Fact_SalesSummaries
 where convert(date, cast(MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101) between 
 dateadd(mm, -3, convert(date, cast(t1.MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(t1.YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101))
 and convert(date, cast(t1.MonthBlended as varchar(2))+ '/01/' + cast(t1.YearBlended as varchar(4)), 101)
 ) as CountALLPrior3Month
 from Fact_SalesSummaries t1
```

```html
BidWonDate                BidWon  CountWonPrior3Month CountAllPrior3Month
-----------------------   ------  ------------------- -------------------
2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
NULL                     0       618                 1048
2014-07-11 00:00:00.000   1       618                 1048
```

Well trying this in a measure does work but does not calculate correctly any help would be greatly appreciated.

I included a sql script that will give you a random data sample that will match the data I have. Run the script and it will generate a random dates or nulls that you can run the dax expression against. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you post some sample data, and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to DAX and PowerBI,

as i've understood the calculate function, i think your second parameter is what's causing u the error, the second param must be a filter, you are not fitering anything in your case, you are just returning a range of dates,

i'm really trying to be helful even know i might be getting it wrong, anyway wouldnt hurt if you try it :D

Comment: Even removing the second one does not effect the results are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of records from the current date going back 3 months can be done with the following measure.

```
enumerator =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Fact_SalesSummaries ),
    DATESINPERIOD (
        'Fact_SalesSummaries'[BidDateWon],
        LASTDATE ( 'Fact_SalesSummaries'[BidDateWon] ),
        3,
        MONTH
    ),
    Fact_SalesSummaries[BidDateWon] <> BLANK ()
)
```

The fact your lost bids dont have dates makes it difficult to get this accurate, because you have to rely on the ordinal (and hopefully contiguous) numbering of the ID's to create the denominator.

```
denominator =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Fact_SalesSummaries[ID] ) - MIN ( Fact_SalesSummaries[ID] )
        + 1,
    DATESINPERIOD (
        'Fact_SalesSummaries'[BidDateWon],
        LASTDATE ( 'Fact_SalesSummaries'[BidDateWon] ),
        -3,
        MONTH
    )
)
```

If you had dates in the rows where the bidwon=false, you could use the same calclation as the enumerator, just removing the last filter.